# Change maximum speaking rate in windows (or balabolka)

Tags: windows-10, text-to-speech

sorry if this is potentially the wrong place (feel free to tell me where I should move it). I'm on a mac running windows 10 through bootcamp.

I use a text to speech program called [balabolka](http://www.cross-plus-a.com/balabolka.htm):

> Balabolka is a Text-To-Speech (TTS) program. All computer voices installed on your system are available to Balabolka. The on-screen text can be saved as a WAV, MP3, MP4, OGG or WMA file. The program can read the clipboard content, view text from documents, customize font and background colour, control reading from the system tray or by the global hotkeys. Supported file formats: AZW, AZW3, CHM, DjVu, DOC, DOCX, EML, EPUB, FB2, HTML, LIT, MOBI, ODS, ODT, PDB, PRC, PDF, RTF, TCR, WPD, XLS, XLSX.

Anyway, it's very helpful, but I've gotten to the point where it's just not reading fast enough for me. I know you can adjust the reading speed slider, but max isn't as fast as I want.

Does anyone know if there's a way to increase the rate beyond what it currently is. I was thinking maybe editing the voice files themselves?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem as you. For me, the solution is to save the speech in MP3 at full speed and then use Audacity to cut a part of the stops and to increase speed. Then change the tone down a bit until feeling comfortable.

I see it works more or less understandable with:

- **10 Speed in Balabolka** (which is like 482 words per second) and save as MP3 file. Use divide and save audio if the text is too long, like epub ebooks.
- **Open the MP3 file with [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/download)**
- OPTIONAL - Cutting silences to 50% (but it’s better to leave it as it is)
- **Increase speed** to 1.33 at max (33% extra),
  which is like 640 words per minute.
- **Change Tone** to -24% or the number you feel comfortable with.

That’s the option I found for myself, but I would like to find a better one.

The best future solution would be to edit the sounds of the speech software to make it easier to understand at high speeds. Because with the current sound it sounds really hard to understand if you go 700 words per minute and beyond.

Comment: Yeah. I usually use a mac, so I just use faster software. I also found a chrome extension that reads faster and well. Here's a vid of how to use it: https://youtu.be/I6-q-num3wk and how to go faster: https://youtu.be/mJN7yMXInew problem is I want to have it integrated in balabolka, but I'm sure you already know that.